# How to fix 'not copying an range to new row'

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an save button that will copy/paste the previous answer to a new row. But not just one, I want it to save up as many as you can, listing them below each other.

It is just for a school project, to make a master cheat sheet.

```vb
Private Sub Save1_Click()

    Dim rA5 As Range
    Set rA5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A5:E5")

    Dim rA7 As Range
    Set rA7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A7:E7")

    If (Range("rA7").Value <> "") Then
        If (Range("rA7").Offset(1).Value <> "") Then
            Set rA7 = rA7.End(xlDown)
        End If

        Set rA7 = rA7.Offset(1)
    End If

    rA7.Value = rA5.Value
End Sub
```

It only pastes the A5:E5 to A7:E7.
It doesn't go down after that to A8:E8, A9:E9 (and so on)

[Preferred outcome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faCxL.png)

Comment: Could you please provide an image with the desirable outcome?

Comment: Added the image. I want the next answer to be saved under the number 1.
So you can track your own history of calculations

Comment: I think you want to use a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment on your own question, it looks like you want the newly calculated value on the top line, and the rest pushed down a line. If that is right, then @Error1004 answer won't work as it sticks your values on the end. The following is his code with an added reverse loop which will stick your new value on the top line and push it down:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Check if there is a value in A5
        If .Range("A5").Value <> "" Then
            'Copy range("A5:E5")
            .Range("A5:E5").Copy
            'If range A7 is empty
            If .Range("A7").Value = "" Then
                .Range("A7:E7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Else
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                i = LastRow
                Do While i > 7
                .Range("A" & (i + 1) & ":E" & (i + 1)).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Value
                i = i - 1
                Loop
                .Range("A7:E7").Value = .Range("A5:E5").Value
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no available data to be save."
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Credit to @Error1004 as I cannibalised his answer for this code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Check if there is a value in A5
        If .Range("A5").Value <> "" Then
            'Copy range("A5:E5")
            .Range("A5:E5").Copy
            'If range A7 is empty
            If .Range("A7").Value = "" Then
                .Range("A7:E7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Else
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                .Range(.Cells(LastRow + 1, "A"), .Cells(LastRow + 1, "E")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no available data to be save."
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I will try to figure out how your code works, because I am pretty new to this. Thanks for the help!